# Tracing points around a curve/ellipse

Tags: conic-sections

Sorry if this has been asked before but my maths days are long behind me.

What I want to know is how to find out the coordinates along the circumference of an ellipse.

So supposing I am at point X,Y which lies on the circumference, and I am traveling at velocity  Z. How can i work out after given time t what the new X,Y values would be.

seems so simple but just cant think where to start.

Thanks for the help

Aaron

Comment: is the speed constant?

Comment: yes it is and its z

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iUfu9RK6w44

Comment: @WillJagy are you aware this link is to a song?

Comment: @ChuckFernández, yes, DevilWAH wrote "my maths days are long behind me" in a rather forlorn manner. The song says no, not really. Here is a different one: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KHVYBiVKldU

Comment: Now we're talking...

Comment: james holmes ... lol

Comment: Yes speed constant relitive to the line, between the two calculated point. And mow I shall return to watching the videos and dreaming of better days ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this has a nice elementary solution -- since the *period* of such a solution would be the circumference of the ellipse, something that it hard enough to compute that it has [its own class of special functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) associated with it.

So in practice you need to do it numerically, and then it's easy enough to program. You know (I hope) how to generate points on the ellipse *without* the constant-velocity requirement:

$$ u \mapsto (a\cos u, b\sin u)$$
where $u$ is a parameter and $2a$ and $2b$ are the lengths of the ellipse's major and minor axes. Your only problem is then to find the next $u$ value at each step. If you do it with small enough steps you can simply differentiate this expression to find out how far a small change in $u$ makes the point move. You get something like
$$ u(t+\Delta t) = u(t) + \frac{z\Delta t}{\sqrt{a^2\sin^2(u(t))+b^2\cos^2(u(t))}}$$
where you choose the time step $\Delta t$ by trial and error to be small enough that the speed ends up being close enough to constant for your needs.

Comment: Cool cheers for that, seems like this is a little more complex than I had hopped. This is some thing I will defiantly be coming back to soon. I am currently moving the point using the first equation you gave, and for now this will do. Once I have the rest of the application in place, I want to come back to this to fine tune it, however for now I think my current method will do fine. Thanks for the solution though.

Comment: @Devil, spelling tip: You mean "definitely", not "defiantly" -- the latter means "while openly refusing to obey".

Comment: :) yer that would be the one. but honestly to my mind those two words look identical, takes a bit of looking for me to see the difference. Thats dyslexics for you.